# Connecting Localhost with external device for testing

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing android app using Google Cloud Messaging. I am using external server xampp and testing it on external mobile(no emulator as it is slow). This is basically chatting app. I am facing problem in getting connection.
I know i need to use http://10.0.2.2:8080 ip for testing if I am using emulator in my client code.
and somehow I need to use router ip http://192.168.x.xx:8080 if I want to test it on external device. I need some guidance as how to configure things to make it possible.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: What device do you need? https://www.ironlab.io/ allows debugging on real devices. They are in free beta now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its external but still local (not on the internet), then both have to be on the same network.

make sure you can access the app its self using the ip address. [image]

Try to enter it into your browser, if you can access the app, then proceed to using it as the ip in android.

you can use tools like `Connectify`(windows), `ap-hotspot`(linux) to setup a network ip. which your phone can connect to.

Comment: Thanks you friends this helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Google Chrome port forwarding as mentioned below
**Step 1:**
Enter `chrome://inspect/#devices` as mentioned below in your desktop chrome window
Chrome window will also show the device name, model number, and the ip address.
**Chrome Remote Debugging Devices Detection**
[image: Chrome Remote Debugging Devices Detection]

**Step 2:**
Add the port in the ports to forward it and to be accessible on the device as shown below.
Click on the button Port Forwarding and check the Discover USB devices.
You will get a small modal as below, where you can enter your localhost address and access it via app on the external devices easily.
Then, after adding the address, check the Enable Port Forwarding.
You are all set done for accessing it on the external device. 
**Chrome Port Forwarding Settings for Remote Debugging on Android**
[image: Chrome Remote Debugging Window]

Chrome on your Android external device also should be open simultaneously to view the output.

**Step 3:**
Then use the url opened up in the device in the App to directly test on the External Device
**Desktop(Development Machine)**
[image: Hosting a localhost on Desktop after remote debugging enabled]
**Android(External Device)**
[image: After remote debugging enabled page on Android Device]

**Note:**

> 1.The device should be connected with a USB cable to the development
>       computer which has forwarded the port, else the connection is lost.
>   2.This mode is not available in Incognito Mode in Chrome